# Moving object to exact location rotation of other object

Tags: properties

I have two object one is in a slightly different location and rotation than the other. I would like to move the first object to the exact location rotation as the second object so I can animate between the two positions. Is there a easier way to do this than just messing with the location and rotation until it looks like they are in the exact same spot?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

one way..

- Select all the objects you want to align, with the target last, so active.
- In the target's Item > Transform panel in the 3D View, select a 'Location' field, Right-click, > 'Copy all to Selected'
- Repeat for Rotation.

Comment: The problem is they where added from separate .obj files so they both have 0 XYZ locations and rotations.